# Yii2: my new action is not found - 404

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-actions

I am trying to call a custom action by ajax, but the response returned is 404, I am pretty sure its a routing issue, but I can't figure how to solve it.
here is my code:

action

```
public function actionGetOne($id){
    $model = Driver::findOne($id);
    if(!empty($model)){
        $data = [];
        $row = [
            'id'=>$model->id,
            'full_name'=>$model->full_name,
            'email'=>$model->email,
            'nationality_id'=>$model->nationality_id,
            'current_location'=>$model->current_location,
            'medical_check_id'=>$model->medical_check_id,
            'img'=>$model->img,
            'current_fleet_id'=>$model->current_fleet_id,
            'availability'=>$model->availability
        ];
        $data[] = $row;
        echo json_encode(['driver-getOne'=>'success','data'=>$data]);
    } else{
        echo json_encode(['driver-getOne'=>'failure']);
    }
}
```

ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url:'<?= urldecode(Url::toRoute(['driver/get-one'])); ?>?id=<?= $id; ?>',
    method:'post',
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(response){}
    error:function(){
        alert('target action is not found!');
    }
}
```

backend/config/params.php

```
<?php
return [
    'adminEmail' => 'admin@example.com',
    'urlRules' => [
        '' => 'site/index',
        'login/' => 'site/login',
        'signup/' => 'site/signup',
        '<controller:[\w-]+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:[\w-]+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:[\w-]+>/create' => '<controller>/create',
        '<controller:[\w-]+>/update/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/update',
        '<controller:[\w-]+>/delete/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/delete',
        '<controller:[\w-]+>/get-all' => '<controller>/get-all',
        '<controller:[\w-]+>/get-one' => '<controller>/get-one',
        '<controller:[\w-]+>/update-status' => '<controller>/update-status',
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change few things and try again.

Action:

```
public function actionGetOne($id)
{
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $model = Driver::findOne($id);
    if (empty($model)) {
        return ['driver-getOne' => 'failure'];
    }
    return [
        'driver-getOne' => 'success',
        'data' => [[
            'id' => $model->id,
            'full_name' => $model->full_name,
            'email' => $model->email,
            'nationality_id' => $model->nationality_id,
            'current_location' => $model->current_location,
            'medical_check_id' => $model->medical_check_id,
            'img' => $model->img,
            'current_fleet_id' => $model->current_fleet_id,
            'availability' => $model->availability
        ]],
    ];
}
```

Action should `return` something to properly finish response sequence otherwise unwanted things can happen. By setting response format you can get JSON encoded array automatically.

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'<?= Url::to(['driver/get-one', 'id' => $id]) ?>',
    method:'post',
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(response){}
    error:function(){
        alert('target action is not found!');
    }
}
```

Get your URL using proper syntax.

Params:

```
'urlRules' => [
    '' => 'site/index',
    'login' => 'site/login',
    'signup' => 'site/signup',
    '<controller:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
    '<controller:[\w-]+>/<action:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:[\w-]+>/<action:[\w-]+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
]
```

I'm assuming you are passing `urlRules` to `components > urlManager > rules` otherwise URL rules won't work.
I removed redundant rules. In general add general rules last and specific rules first.

Comment: Thank you for your enhancements, but this won't solve my issue. The problem was due to the camel case naming of the action.

Comment: Not really. `GetOne` action name is translated in routing as `get-one` but you missed the proper regex pattern (`[\w-]+` instead of `\w+`) so there was no routing match. I've corrected it and fix other things as well because I'm nice that way ;)